# INVALID_CLIENT spotify SDK android

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, spotify, spotify-app

```
{"message":"Client authentication failed:INVALID_CLIENT"}
com.spotify.android.appremote.api.error.AuthenticationFailedException: {"message":"Client authentication failed:INVALID_CLIENT"}
```

I'm doing integration to the spotify SDK with native Android, following the tutorial provided by spotify, and attempting to run me returns this error. I have already created an Application in the dashboard and I already have my Id Client generated. If anyone can help me thank you.